# popup mask is very very quickly shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e772g9zq/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="x">
</div>

<input class="clickMe" type="button" value="ClickMe"></input>
```

JS

```
  $(".clickMe").click(
            function()
            {
               $('.x').show().css('top',0).addClass("mask"); 
            }
        );
```

CSS:

```
.x
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
        position: relative;
        top: -210px;
        transition: all 1s ease 0s;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .mask::before
    {
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        content:"";
        background-color: #777;
    }
    .mask::after
    {
        content: "";
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity: 0.5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .mask
    {
        transition: all 2s ease 0s;
    }
```

If you see in the fiddle after clicking the button, mask comes very earlier. But popup comes very slowly due to transition effect. I added the same transition to mask. But there is no effect.

How do i achieve the same transition with the mask also? Or is there any best ways to show popup and mask?

Any ideas?

Comment: Put `$('.x').show().css('top',0).addClass("mask"); ` in a [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: No It doesn't. Same delay after timeout milliseconds. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e772g9zq/6/)

Comment: Do you have to use a pseudo class :before for the overlay mask?

Comment: Have you tried to have the background and square as different objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a separate div for the fade in as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugj5d1ab/).

html:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

js:

```
$('.overlay').addClass('visible');
```

css:

```
.x
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
        position: absolute;
        top: -210px;
        right:0;
        transition: all 1s ease 0s;
        margin-right: 20px;
        z-index:10;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    .overlay
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:-1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        transition : all 1s linear;        
        opacity:0;

    }
    .visible{
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:5;
    }
```

Here is an updated fiddle that has the mask over everything but the popup.
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vowmh1mu/)

Comment: [Good one](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/zoLnz7tg/2/) But popup background is below to the mask. I changed z-index and it fails. I am also trying and do u have any idea?

Comment: [Modified one](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/zoLnz7tg/3/) Got it working. Plus one let me wait for few more best answers

Comment: I see what you mean, I think your option and mine would not be a very good 'popup mask' though, because you'd want the mask to cover everything but the popup I would assume. I'll work on that real quick.

Comment: I've added another fiddle to my answer with it working as you need I believe.

Comment: changed a few css position, z-index values, and bg color. You could compare the two fiddle links in my answer :)